# Can there be an if statement in a sequence?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

Just trying to enhance a part of this code, and I was wondering if I could include an if statement in a sequence? I want to slow down the spawning of debris when the debris count is greater than 10.

This is the current code:

```
-(void)spawnDebris {
    //debris
    SKSpriteNode * debris = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"debris1.png"] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    debris.zPosition = 1.0;

    debris.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:15];
    debris.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO; 
    debris.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionDebris;

    RandomPosition = arc4random() %248;
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 34;
    debris.position = CGPointMake (RandomPosition, self.size.height + 40);

    [_debris addObject:debris];
    [self addChild:debris];

    //next Spawn:
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
          [SKAction waitForDuration:2],
          [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris) onTarget:self],
    ]]];

    if (_dead == YES) {
        [self removeAllActions];
    }

}
```

Where `_debris` is an `NSMutableArray`. So essentially the `SKSpriteNodes` are being added every 2 seconds, but to change it up, I wanted to have their `waitForDurations` to change after the `_debris` count is over a certain number.

This is what I thought to do:

```
 //next Spawn:
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
          [SKAction waitForDuration:2],
          [SKAction runBlock:^{
                 if (_debris.count > 10) {
                      [SKAction waitForDuration:7];
                 }
    }],
          [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris) onTarget:self],
    ]]];
```

But this didn't work. Is it even possible to use an if statement in a sequence? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Was there any error logged, how did it not work?

Comment: No error logged, just ran as if it would without the if statement for some reason, (every 2 seconds) @JoePasq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code won't work because the `[SKAction waitForDuration:7]` is not executed.

Much easier would be:

```
float time = 2.0;

if (_debris.count > 10) { time = 9.0; }

[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
      [SKAction waitForDuration:time],
      [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris) onTarget:self],
]]];
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

The block declares a `waitForDuration` action but never runs it on anything.

Try

```
   [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
      [SKAction waitForDuration:2],
      [SKAction runBlock:^{
             if (_debris.count > 10) {
                  [self runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:7]];
             }
}],
      [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnDebris) onTarget:self],
]]];
```

Comment: You may need to declare a weak reference to self. You would do that outside the block with `__weak weakSelf = self; ` and then use that to read the debris count and run the action on that weakSelf.

Comment: I tried that one, too. But the `runBlock:` action won't wait until `[self runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:7]];` is finished. Instead, it runs parallel to the next `SKAction` in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a random number generator to make it more interesting.

Instead of the if statement and all that, simply replace 2 with arc4random()% x (< choose a number) then it will spawn randomly every x seconds.